# How to change url structure of yii2 (from controller/view?id= to view/id)

Tags: yii2

How to change url structure of yii2 (from **controller/view?id=** to **controller/view/id**)

Comment: enable pretty urls in frontend/config/main.php (this is for yii2 advanced app)

Comment: I have already enabled pretty url.  Here it is my url in frontend/config/main.php

Comment: @MuhammadShahzad This is not enough because OP wants to change the way of passing id as parameter, so url rule must be applied.

Comment: 'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,

        ],

Comment: @Rustam Besides that, you need to add url rule.

Comment: I want url to be like :http://test.advanced.loc/member/profile/view/c_id/1. Currently, it is http://test.advanced.loc/member/profile/view?c_id=1

Comment: @Rustam Added this option to my answer as well.

Comment: Thanks, I found answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you already enabled pretty url rules, so you need to add url rule. Add this to your app config:

```
return [
    'components' => [
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'rules' => [
                'controller/view/<id:\d+>' => 'controller/view',
            ],
        ],
    ],
]
```

> I want url to be like `:test.advanced.loc/member/profile/view/c_id/1`. Currently, it is `test.advanced.loc/member/profile/view?c_id=1`

In this case url rule should be:

```
'member/profile/view/c_id/<c_id:\d+>' => 'member/profile/view',
```

More info and examples can be found in [offical docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#url-rules).